# Editing Dynamically Generated Telerikmvc3 Grid

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, telerik-grid, telerik-mvc

I have a dynamically generated MVC3 grid that is populated from a ViewModel. I need to add editing to the grid and cant get it to even go into edit mode.

Also I need to be able to make some of the columns readonly.

My code is below:

```
@(Html.Telerik()
    .Grid<System.Data.DataRow>(Model.Data.Rows.Cast<System.Data.DataRow>())
    .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width: 2500px" })
    .Name("Grid")
        .ToolBar(tb => tb.Template("Outstanding Orders"))
        .DataKeys(dataKeys => dataKeys.Add("DeliveryID"))
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Command(commands =>
        {
            commands.Edit().ButtonType(GridButtonType.ImageAndText)
                .HtmlAttributes( 
                new
                {
                    style = "width: 60px; min-width: 40px; background: #0066FF"
                });
        }).Width(100).Title("Commands");
        columns.Command(commandbutton =>
        {
            commandbutton.Select().ButtonType(GridButtonType.ImageAndText)
                .HtmlAttributes(
                new
                {
                    style = "width: 60px; min-width: 40px; background: #0066FF"
                });

        columns.LoadSettings(Model.Columns as IEnumerable<GridColumnSettings>);
    })
    .DataBinding(dataBinding => dataBinding.Server()
                .Select("_DeliveryGrid", "Deliveries")
            .Update("Save", "Deliveries"))
    .Editable(editing => editing.Mode(GridEditMode.InLine))
    .Sortable(settings => settings.Enabled(true))
    .Scrollable(c => c.Height("9000px"))
    .EnableCustomBinding(true)
    .Resizable(resize => resize.Columns(true))
)
```

My viewmodel definition

```
public class DeliveriesGridViewModel
{
    public DataTable Data { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<GridColumnSettings> Columns { get; set; }
}
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: "cant get it to even go into edit mode" what do you mean by this?

Comment: @Tx3 - When I click the "Edit" button it posts to my controller to get the data then just goes back to the Grid and doesn't go into Edit mode. It just displays the grid again.

Comment: Any errors in the Console (F12 in the browser)?

Comment: There is a telerik library error: Telerik.grid.min.js. Shows error as 
SyntaxError: missing ; before statement
[Break On This Error]  

return data.Delivery Name;

Answer (score 1):

If  you are binding to a **DataTable** or something similar make sure that the properties you bind the columns to does not contains white spaces.

i.e. "Delivery Name" should be "DeliveryName"

Comment: so the column headers/titles cant have spaces in them, is that what you are saying?

Comment: I removed the spaces from the columns. Now I am getting this error
SyntaxError: identifier starts immediately after numeric literal

This is happening on columns that start with a number. Ex 8GHSDimm.

Any ideas on this one?

Thanks

Comment: I removed all the spaces as you suggested and the columns that start with a digit I put an _ in front of them.  Thanks so much for your info, I have been working trying to figure this one out for quite a while. But it still wont drop into edit mode. When I click the edit button it just returns back to my grid.